# How to remove old lens when changing the new lens in jQuery.ImageLens?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am changing the lens size dynamically, when I tried to change size of lens the new size lens appeared properly but old lens retained in same image, here I want to remove old lens.

I referred from  this link http://www.dailycoding.com/Uploads/2011/03/imageLens/demo.html

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2STKN/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#img001').imageLens({ lensSize: 100 });
});

function changesize()
{
    $('#img001').imageLens({ lensSize: 400 });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SivaLingamDCI/2STKN/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change

```
var target = $("<div style='" + lensStyle + "' class='" + options.lensCss + "'>&nbsp;</div>").appendTo($("body"));
```

in the source code of imageLens to

```
if (obj.data("imageLens")) {
    obj.data("imageLens").obj.remove();
}

var target = $("<div style='" + lensStyle + "' class='" + options.lensCss + "'>&nbsp;</div>").appendTo($("body"));

obj.data("imageLens", { obj: target });
```

This makes sure that we add `imageLens` as data refering to the created `<div>` and check if it already has one, and if it does, remove it.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2STKN/6/)